# Details on executing Ruby code using Sinatra

Tags: html, ruby, sinatra, erb

I have a Ruby script :

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'
require 'pp'
require 'opal'
require 'ostruct'


url = URI("MY URI")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request["content-type"] = 'application/json'
request["authorization"] = 'MY AUTH'
request["cache-control"] = 'no-cache'

response = http.request(request)

result = JSON.parse(response.body)

if response.code == "200"

    result.each do |doc|
    #      puts doc
           print doc ["id"]
           print " "
           print doc ["is_completed"]
           print " "
           print doc ["name"]
           print "\n"
    end
else
        puts "error"
end
```

This is working correctly.

What I have done is :

1) installed Sinatra

2) I am able to run a ruby file and see the localhost show something.

What I need to do

- is show the results of the above script ( some api data that i am parsing ), onto the localhost html page.

As mentioned, I have the Sinatra gem and just doing a simple "hello world" does show on the localhost site. The main thing I am looking for is what can I do to show the results of the above scripts on the site.

Thanks in advance.

Update : I setup my code as follows,

```
require 'sinatra' 

get '/' go 
code = "<%= MY ENTIRE CODE I POSTED ABOVE %>" 
erb code 
end
```

When I go to localhost, I am getting the entire response of the API call which is in the "result" variable. The "print" statements are still displaying on the terminal where script is executed.

So now the question is, how do I send specific data over to the webpage. Such as in the "print" statements. Thanks. Hope that is clear.

Comment: Have yo tried reading the docs on rendering an HTML page? http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html

Comment: "Ruby" is not an acronym, so it doesn't need to be all-caps.

Comment: @nicooga Thanks for pointing me to that site.

looks like i was able to do this :
`code`
require 'sinatra'
get '/' go
code = "<%= MY ENTIRE CODE I POSTED ABOVE %>"
erb code
end
`code`
I believe that lead me to another question. The API result in it's totality is being now displayed on the localhost site. That is GREAT !!! at least i got that far. BUT in the code, the puts are being displayed on the terminal. How can I get around displaying the puts on the site and not the entire result of the API response ? hope that made sense....

Comment: Please [edit] your question to reflect what you've managed to do thus far (with code) and what your new question is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find an answer for this and now I have it working exactly how I need it.

Final Code :

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do

require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'
require 'json'
require 'pp'
require 'opal'
require 'ostruct'

url = URI('MY URI FOR DATA')

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
request['content-type'] = 'application/json'
request['authorization'] = 'MY AUTH INFO'
request['cache-control'] = 'no-cache'
request['postman-token'] = 'b1dfa857-69f3-dc2e-3c23-ae60632891cb'

response = http.request(request)

jhash = JSON.parse(response.body)
output = ''

jhash.each do |doc|
   title_tag = doc ["id"]
   info_item = doc ["name"]
   output << "<TR><td>#{title_tag}</td><td>#{info_item}</td></tr>"
end

  erb :index, :locals => {results: output}

end
```

The index.erb file contains nothing but :

```
<table>
  <th>The Weather in Buffalo, NY, USA</th>
  <tr>
    <td><%= results %></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The results are now what I was looking for. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: It's good form to put the `require` statements at the top of the file, they don't belong within the `get` block.